# bash: Delete all files older than 1 month, but leave files from Mondays

Tags: bash, sh

I have a lot of daily backup archives. To manage disk usage, I need a bash script that will delete all files older than 1 month, but keep all files created on Mondays, even if they are older than 1 month.

For example, this will delete all files last modified more than 30 days ago:

```
 find /path/to/files* -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

But I don't really know how to keep files created on Mondays.

Comment: This will erase all files older than 30j.
find / -name "*" -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {}\;
You mean you want to keep files created on monday even if they are older than 1 month ?

Comment: yes, right. Will change the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Slightly simpler and more cautious version of @JoSo's answer:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c 'test $(date +%a -r "$1") = Mon || echo rm "$1"' -- {} \;
```

The differences:

- Using `date -r` to get the last modification date of a file directly
- Using `%a` to work with more comprehensible weekday names
- Just echo the `rm "$1"` first to review what will be deleted. If looks good, then either stick `| sh` at the end to really execute, or remove the `echo`

However, @JoSo is right to point out that `date +%a` is locale dependent, so these versions would be indeed safer:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c 'test $(date +%u -r "$1") = 1 || echo rm "$1"' -- {} \;
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c 'test $(LC_TIME=C date +%a -r "$1") = Mon || echo rm "$1"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Kudos for the `-r` switch. But I'd rather not use `%a` because it's locale-dependent. It's probably safe when you prepend `LC_TIME=C` to the date command.

Answer (score 7):

As `find` to my knowledge has no weekday check, you need to call an external program.

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c \
        '[ "$(date +%u -d @"$(stat -c %Y "$1")")" != 1 ] && rm "$1"' -- {} \;
```

Update: Using the `-r` switch to `date` (Kudos to Janos) and only testing, not deleting inside the shell command probably yields the cleanest possible version:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c 'test "$(date +%u -r "$1")" != 1' -- {} \; \
    -print  # or -delete instead
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
stat -c %y yourfile
```

to get the date the file was created.

Then extract the date with cut to have a var like myvar=yyyymmdd

and finally use

```
date +%u --d $myvar
date +%u --d 20130822
```

it will return the day of week, if it returns 1 it was monday.
In my case it return 4 because 22/08/2013 was a Thursday

Edit : if you can get all these working as a simple command line as Jo So suggest, it's better !

Answer (score 0):

What about avoiding subprocesses in loop:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 -printf '%Ta %p\n' \
    | grep -v ^Mon | cut -c5- | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rm -v
```