# Bash script to remove files older than 15 months

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script, if I want to remove files older than 15 days in a directory, I can run:

```
find "$DIR" -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

Can someone help me with a bash script to remove files older than 15 months in a directory?

Is this the same as ctime in Bash?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034415/bash-delete-all-files-older-than-1-month-but-leave-files-from-mondays?rq=1

Comment: But thats 1 month. I dont see a solution similar to what I want

Comment: -mtime +65w maybe for 65 weeks, on the basis 1 year is 52 weeks and a quarter of a year is therefore 13 weeks and 52+13 = 65

Answer (score 4):

According to the man page:

```
 -mtime n[smhdw]
         If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last modification time and the time find was started, rounded up to the next
         full 24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.

         If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last modification time and the time find was started is exactly n units.  Please
         refer to the -atime primary description for information on supported time units.
```

Then, at `-atime`:

```
 -atime n[smhdw]
         If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last access time and the time find was started, rounded up to the next full
         24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.

         If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last access time and the time find was started is exactly n units.  Possible
         time units are as follows:

         s       second
         m       minute (60 seconds)
         h       hour (60 minutes)
         d       day (24 hours)
         w       week (7 days)

         Any number of units may be combined in one -atime argument, for example, ``-atime -1h30m''.  Units are probably only useful when used in conjunction with the + or - modi-
         fier.
```

So we have weeks. 15 months * 4 weeks/month = 60 weeks.

```
find $DIR -type f -mtime +60w -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Is +60w same if I am using ctime?

Comment: Note that 15 months is probably more like 65 weeks...  on the basis 1 year is 52 weeks and a quarter of a year is therefore 13 weeks and 52+13 = 65

Comment: @user3409351: Yes, the format is the same. As can be read in the man page…

Answer (score 0):

use 450 (=15*30) as `-mtime` parameter.

```
find $DIR -type f -mtime +450 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Is +450 same if I am using ctime?

Answer (score 0):

A funny possibility: you can `touch` a tmp file with timestamp `15 months ago` and use it with the (negated) `-newer` flag of `find`:

```
a=$(mktemp)
touch -d '15 months ago' -- "$a"
find "$DIR" -type f \! -newer "$a" -exec rm {} +
rm -- "$a"
```

This, of course, assumes that your `touch` and `find` have these capabilities.

If there's a chance that `mktemp` creates the file in subdirectories of your directory `$DIR`, it will get very messy as the file refered to by "$a" could be deleted before the end of the process. In this case, to be 100% sure, use the (negated) `-samefile` test:

```
find "$DIR" -type f \! -newer "$a" \! -samefile "$a" -exec rm {} +
```

You can of course use the `-delete` command of `find` if your `find` supports it. That would give:

```
a=$(mktemp)
touch -d '15 months ago' -- "$a"
find "$DIR" -type f \! -newer "$a" \! -samefile "$a" -delete
rm -- "$a"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch designed for exactly this application.  Typically used with cron.