# How to delete files with spaces 20 days are more senior, having left the last 4 even if they are more senior than 20 days?

Tags: bash, sh

How to delete files with spaces 20 days are more senior, having left the last 4 even if they are more senior than 20 days?

Examples of files (where in name 1 - the oldest file):

```
reckless 1.txt
reckless 2.txt
reckless 3.txt
reckless 4.txt
reckless 5.txt
reckless 6.txt
reckless 7.txt
reckless 8.txt
confidence1.txt
confidence2.txt
confidence3.txt
choke-1.txt
choke-2.txt
choke-3.txt
choke-4.txt
choke-5.txt
choke-6.txt
choke-7.txt
choke-8.txt
choke-9.txt
choke-10.txt
cruel_1_1.txt
cruel_1_2.txt
cruel_1_3.txt
cruel_1_4.txt
cruel_1_5.txt
cruel_2_1.txt
cruel_2_2.txt
cruel_2_3.txt
cruel_2_4.txt
cruel_2_5.txt
cruel_2_6.txt
cruel_2_7.txt
level_1.txt
```

It turns out that should be deleted from this list:

```
reckless 1.txt
reckless 2.txt
reckless 3.txt
reckless 4.txt
choke-1.txt
choke-2.txt
choke-3.txt
choke-4.txt
choke-5.txt
choke-10.txt
cruel_1_1.txt
cruel_2_1.txt
cruel_2_2.txt
cruel_2_3.txt
```

Tried something similar from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034914

But did not understand how to make sorting according to a necessary condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each filename does not contain newline characters,
please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    array=()
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        [[ $file =~ ^[0-9]+\ (.*)$ ]] && array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
    done < <(
    find . -name "$line*.txt" -type f -mtime +20 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort
    )
    for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}-4; i++ )); do
        rm -- "${array[$i]}"
    done
done < <(
for f in *.txt; do
    [[ $f =~ ^(.*)[-_\ ]+[0-9]+\.txt$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done | uniq
)
```

**[Explanations]**

- First of all, it removes the suffix numbers and extensions from the filenames
  to extract a root name as a group name.
- Next it finds individual group files which are older than 20 days and
  sort them by mtime.
- Then it removes older files preserving the latest up to four files in the
  group.

If the filenames *do* contain newline characters, small modification and `-z`
option support of `sort` command will answer the requirement.